# Typecasting.Difference between String() and + ''

Tags: javascript

Whats dif. between  2 methods :

```
null+'';
"null"
undefined + ''
"undefined"
NaN + ''
"NaN"
String(undefined)
"undefined"
String(null)
"null"
```

May have features to keep in mind ? maybe they are completely identical and performance ?

Comment: The results are identical. If you want to know about the performance, use jsperf.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In all the examples, the second way is using String literals to create strings. In the following cases,

```
null + ''
undefined + ''
NaN + ''
```

Since we concatenate with a string, the previous objects are also converted to their corresponding String representation. In the following expressions,

```
String(undefined)
String(null)
```

`String` constructor is used to construct the String representation of the objects. Internally, both `String(undefined)` and `undefined + ''` will be using the same function to convert to String representation.

I would say, using a single string literal may have a slight performance advantage over the other methods, because other methods will determine the string values at runtime but the JavaScript implementations can understand the String literals during compile time itself.

Answer (score 1):

They will all return the same value, a string representation of a false-y value.

However, performance can vary radically.

http://jsperf.com/converting-null-undefined-nan-to-string

For instance, recent versions of Chrome and Firefox (35.0 and 28.0 at time of test, respectively) handle `NaN + ''` far more efficiently than `String(NaN)`, whereas `String()` is more efficient for `undefined` and `null`. Safari 7.0 couldn't care less.

In more common cases (e.g. converting a `Number` to a `String`), concatenating an empty string vs. creating a new object vs. `.toString()` has been a subject of contention for a while. The results are interesting.

http://jsperf.com/string-vs-tostring-vs-empty-string-value/2

Mileage may vary heavily between browser versions. Also, blah blah premature optimization blah, do whatever is most clear in all but the most performance-sensitive environments. And be wary of unexpected type coercion, especially when checking false-y values.